# Javascript - self-executing functions : why to use them if I can create local scope with not self-executing functions?

Tags: javascript, self-executing-function

I know there are a lot of posts here and elsewhere about selfexecuting functions but I still have some questions after reading posts.

1. why would I ever assign a self-executing function to a variable? If seems that they execute themselves anyways.

   ```
   var myFunc=(function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
   })();
   ```
2. I read a lot that the reason to use self-executing functions is to keep variables private. If I have a not self-executing function, everything I define inside that function is gonna be private anyways?!

   ```
   (function() {
    var name="my Name"
    console.log(name);
   })();

   vs.

    function() {
    var name="my Name"
    console.log(name);
    };
    //its the same
   ```

So I dont quite understand how self-executing functions are to keep local scope (as you can do that using not self-executing functions) so the only reason I see is to use them when you want to execute automatically for example on page load.

Thanks!

just one more question:

```
var test=(function myFunc(){
      var name="Hello World"
      return {
        test1: function(){
          return name;
        },
        test2:function(){
          return name+"1"
        }
      }
    })()

    test.test1()

vs

    var test=function myFunc(){
      var name="Hello World"
      return {
        test1: function(){
          return name;
        },
        test2:function(){
          return name+"1"
        }
      }
    }

    test.test1()
```

--> what exactly happens here that because of IIFE I can actually execute test.test1() and not with a regular function?

Comment: second doesn't executes itself, it only defines the function.

Comment: The function doesn't need to be self-executing but it needs to be ran for it to do what it is meant, and since the only purpose particular is to create a scope, there is no need for it to not self-execute

Comment: At point 1 you're not assigning the function to the variable, but its return value (in this case undefined). It's basically a way to export a single function or object from the closed scope of your function, making it public.

Comment: http://esbueno.noahstokes.com/post/77292606977/self-executing-anonymous-functions-or-how-to-write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually wrap your functions in a anonymous function when you want to keep your scope contained. This is also part of the module pattern which is still pretty popular:

https://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Then you can assign the outcome of that [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to a variable so your scope can only be accessed by calling that variable.

```
myScope.myLocallyScopedProperty or myScope[myLocallyScopedProperty]
```

Your other function needs to be called manually and it also accessible from anywhere.

I suggest reading the article by Todd Moto it explains a lot.

Comment: What I dont understand, what you are saying and what the 'module pattern' says, can be done with a regular function without the need to use IIFE. Thats why I am confused.

Comment: You can do exactly the same but your scope is different though. With the module pattern you can only call your functions in the `IIFE` by calling the property that is directly assigned to it. Without the `IIFE` you can call them from everywhere because they are not contained within a function scope. This can lead to conflicts in your codebase, if you define 2 functions with the same name(which is easy to in a large codebase) you are already screwed.

Comment: Thank you! That point makes sense now :) Just another question, I updated my question based on what you said and Im just wondering what exactly happens that only using IIFE, I can access particular methods which are being returned by my function (I added example code in my question) Thanks!

Comment: In your example code in the first part you assign the outcome of the function in the second part you assign a function itself(which is not executed). Your second example will probably work if you do this: `test().test1()` since then you are executing the function and the return value will actually return a result. Otherwise you are simply passing around a reference to the function.

Comment: If test().test1() works as well, then I again dont understand the benefit of IIFE. The only difference I see is that with IIFE, that I assign the outcome of the function like you said, and always calling the outer function to get the outcome of an inner function ('test().test1() ') is bad for ..?Performance? Or something else? Also, you said:  With the module pattern you can only call your functions in the IIFE by calling the property that is directly assigned to it.  What do you mean by ''in the IIFE" compared to anywhere with the example of test().test1()? Sorry, so many questions. Thanks!!

Comment: `test()` is part of your global scope but `test1()` is not since it is only accessible through `test()`. The benefit is that you are encapsulating properties like `test1()`. They are not in the global scope and you cannot simply call `test1()` without doing `test().test1()`. This prevents naming collisions since you only have to namespace your module with a decent name to prevent modules from colloding. This is usually done by prefixing it with your app name or something unique like that. Modules also allow you to implement private methods like to articles says.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I mean is: the benefit you just explained is not the benefit of IIFE but also the benefit of wrapping functions insight an outer function where also test1 is encapsulated and which prevents name collisions - so whats again so different of IIFE over regular outer functions with inner functions?

Comment: Nothing IIFE is just there to invocate the method straight away so you can access the returned properties of that method without having to invoke it yourself. That is all there is to it, I don't know how I can make this any more clear if you already understand the concept of the scopes here.

Comment: ohh okay. My problem was that every blog or post/answers talk about the benefits to IIFE and Im thinking but thats what can be achieved using outer function too so i didnt understand it. Now im good :) Thank you! Just a last question-is there a benefit of invoking that function at once and not having to execute inner functions myself? Like if you had the choise of either wrapping your functions insight an IIFE or regular function-what would you chose and why? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't see why you would not use an IIFE. If you didn't you would just create an antipattern and force yourself to always invocate the module method before you could access any of its properties. Also if you are not using an IIFE your properties are not function scoped and the entire concept of public/private properties goes out the window.

Comment: What do you mean by ' are not function scoped' if my properties are insight a regular outer function, then they are not public and local to that outer function.

Answer (score 1):

1. If that IIFE doesn't *return* anything, then there's indeed absolutely no use to assign it to anything. Though there may of course be examples of IIFEs returning something you want to use later; in that case the IIFE is a private scope to set up some object for example:

   ```
   var foo = (function () {
       var bar = 'something';
       // here be dragons
       return baz;
   })();
   ```

   This gives you a private scope to assemble `baz` without unnecessarily leaking temporary variables into the global scope.
2. There's no difference in those examples, except that the second one doesn't execute and therefore never does anything. Scoping and the purpose for the scoping are unchanged.

Comment: I still dont understand the use of IIFE since what you are saying could be achived using regular functions. With your example: var foo = function () {
    var bar = 'something';
    // here be dragons
    return baz;
} would do the same.

Comment: No, then `foo` would be a function that when called returns a `baz`. With an IIFE `foo` *is* `baz`, and there's no way to call that function again to construct another `baz`. An IIFE is a one-time function call only, purely for the purpose of creating a temporary private scope.

Comment: so youre saying that IIFE create private temporary scope, and in that example bar will never change because its declared only once (becaue a IIFE is called only once)?

Comment: Yes, `bar` will only exist temporarily while the function is executed, which only happens once.

Answer (score 1):

First, briefly, these are not self-executing functions. (That would be a *recursive* function.) These are inline-invoked function expressions (IIFEs). The *function* doesn't call itself, the expression calls the function.

> why would I ever assign a self-executing function to a variable?

That's not what that code does. It assigns the **result** of calling the IIFE to the variable. You'd use it when you want that result, for instance:

```js
var x = (function() {
    var n = 0;
    return {
        increment: function() { return ++n; }
    };
})();
console.log(typeof x); // "object"
console.log(x.increment()); // 1
console.log(x.increment()); // 2
```

`x` doesn't receive the IIFE, it receives what that IIFE *returns* — in this case, an object with a function on it.

> I read a lot that the reason to use self-executing functions is to keep variables private. If I have a not self-executing function, everything I define inside that function is gonna be private anyways?!

Yes, that's true. You use an IIFE when you only need to do what's inside the IIFE **once**. Otherwise, absolutely, you define the function, give it a name, and then reuse it wherever you need it. The variables inside the function are indeed private to it (unless exposed in some way), and are specific to each call to the function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 'That's not what that code does. It assigns the result of calling the IIFE to the variable. You'd use it when you want that result, for instance:' Here again, I could use a regular function, assign it to a variable and use it whenever i need it. If the only reason to use IIFE is when I need to do whatever is insight it at once like you said, I dont udnerstand why IIFE called the 'module pattern' and used for all kind of stuff (not only to call whats inside the function at once)

Comment: @codingworld: IIFEs are frequently used to *implement* what someone decided to all the "revealing module pattern" many years ago. E.g., `var MyStuff = (function() { /*...*/ })()` where the function has several private things in it and returns an object with public things on it (not unlike my incrementing example). You could do that by defining the function separately and then calling it, but why would you? It's just another identifier, and you don't need it for anything. The IIFE does the job in a nice tidy way.

Comment: @codingworld: Of course, here in 2017, we have proper modules.

Answer (score 1):

> In the form of IIFE (or immediately invoked function expressions), they can then be [used to create plugins](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin) or [used as namespaces](https://www.trainingconnection.com/javascript/lessons/invoked2.php) and attached to window / jquery / or other global level object for use later.

---

When you name a function like assigning anonymous function to a variable, you can use it later by calling the variable with parentheses, in your example, defined myFunc with

```
var myFunc=(function() {
 console.log('Hello World');
});
```

Use it later in code as `myFunc()`;

In your example, you are storing the output of function directly in variable, by calling it immediately, and there is no output to be stored.

So, if you later write `console.log(myFunc);`, there is `undefined` as output.

---

Better IIFE example from your code samples is the one mentioned below.

```
(function() {
 var name="my Name"
 console.log(name);
})();
```

It executes, does a console.log and that's it. Adds nothing to namespace or the global object in your case.

---

The last of your examples defines a function, does not execute it then, and since it does not have a named variable assigned, or a name, it gives syntax error and cannot be used later in code. So, below example is useless.

```
function() {
 var name="my Name"
 console.log(name);
 };
```

---

You have added two more examples with `var test` = `function myFunc`. First one will work fine with `test.test1()`. For the second one, you need to evaluate test as a function first and then call its function, like `test().test1()`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I still have trouble understanding the benefit of self-executing functions over not. You say used for namespaces- but regular functions can do the same, no? I just feel anything a self-executing function can do, a normal one can do as well

Comment: For simple, daily and regular stuff, simple functions are ok. When you are creating libraries for use, which are to be maintained separately by different teams, or creating a plugin which is to be made available for use to someone else, this is the way they do it. How would the end person access all the code under one global object he knows, say jquery. You add your functions to global level object and use from there. These different features and functionalities are available from different files but under one namespace. End user needs to know that one namespace only.

Comment: so when I define functions insight a IIFE -then anywhere in the code I can access them but I cant if I define same functions insight a regular function?!

Comment: Sort of, if you define it inside a IIFE and attach it to a namespace, you can use that. Inside a normal function, you can also do that, but the scope and I would say "distributability of the plugin" will be lesser since every one will have to somehow learn to invoke it. For your regular development purpose, by one team, one project and no team depending on your team's plugin, surely do that. Everyone does that for code which is not to be distributed, and is very normal.

Answer (score 1):

1: To assign an IIFE to a local Variable makes sense for something like that:

```
var getID = (function () {
  var id = 0;
  return function () { return id++; };
})();
```

This way you can get new IDs without running the risk to reset the internal counter from anywhere else in the code, except by redeclaring the variable.

2: Basically you create Scope by creating a function. But if you do not execute it, well, it doesn't do anything. So if you have that:

```
function () { return 'foo' };
```

How do you want to call it if it is not assigned to a variable or does not have a name? By itself it wont do anything, since it is not called. Something like that is dead code and can safely be removed.

Comment: What I meant was more why why assigning the IIFE to a variable. I understand the point of assigning a regular function to a variable, I just dont get why using IIFE and then assigning it.

Answer (score 1):

your first thing has no sense whatsoever:

```
var myFunc = =(function() {
       console.log('Hello World');
    })();
```

`myFunc` is not a function and it is `undefined`.

The sense, as I see it, for a self executing function is to package some code that has to be executed right away.

```
var p1=1, p2=2, obj = {
   prop: (function(x,y){ return x+y;})(p1, p2)
}
```

**OR** 
avoiding overwriting already defined functions/objects in the case your script will be inserted in a already existing application and also creating a kind of private methods, if you like:

```js
function aFunction() {
  console.log('a code');
}
(function(w) {
  function aFunction() {
    console.log('b code');
  }
  w.run = function() {
    aFunction();
  };
})(window)
aFunction();
run();
```

Answer (score 1):

You use self executing functions to expose only what you need out of a scope. I think I have a somewhat clear example:

```
let myObject = (function(){
  let privateVariable = "I'm private";
  function privateMethod() {
    //private method
  };
  function methodToExpose() {
    //this method I will expose
  }

  //what is returned here, is what is public
  return {
    PublicMethod: methodToExpose
    //other public properties
  }
}());
```

So, the function gets executed immediately, and what happens is I have an object that is defined by what I returned from the function.

Another example I could give you is to retain variables of the current scope inside a closure, but you wouldn't really use it that much, since we now have `let`. A practical example:

```
<span id="1">old</span>
<span id="2">old</span>
<span id="3">old</span>
<span id="4">old</span>
<script>
var toPrint = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  toPrint = "new: " + i;
  document.getElementById(i.toString()).addEventListener('click', function(event){ event.target.innerHTML = toPrint; })
}

</script>
```

When you click on a span, the value will be replaced with the value... "new: 4"!
That's because when you finished executing, that's the value that toPrint has. The function assigned to the click event retrieves that toPrint, and at the time it retrieves it, it is "new: 4". We solve this with closures:

```
<span id="1">old</span>
<span id="2">old</span>
<span id="3">old</span>
<span id="4">old</span>
<script>
var toPrint = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  toPrint = "new: " + i;
  document.getElementById(i.toString()).addEventListener('click', function(event){ 
    var currPrint = toPrint;
    return function(event){ event.target.innerHTML = currPrint ; };
  }())
}

</script>
```

By using a self executing function, we save the current value of toPrint in the currPrint variable inside a local scope. When we later click on a span, the function assigned to the click even will use the variable currPrint, which contains the value that toPrint had at the time the function was assigned, not the value that toPrint has at finished execution.

Note that this is solved also by using let instead of var, but still, it's an example of self-executing functions :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So its mostly to create local scope for (also) functions, which then can be accessed later on. For example myObject.PublicMethod() would return to me the function I want in that case and that is only possible using IIFE, if I wrapped both functions in your example insight a regular function, I could return those inner functions but I couldnt access them like that: myObject.PublicMethod(). Creating locals scope helps also to avoid namespace issues in case of a big code base). Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss something here. Just to make basic things clear - if you assign a self executed function to a variable the actual `return value` of the function when executed at this time is assigned to the variable and not the function itself.

```
var myFunc = (function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
})();
myFunc(); // will throw error: TypeError: myFunc is not a function
myFunc === undefined

var myFunc = (function() {
    console.log('Hello World');
    return 'japp';
})();
myFunc(); // will throw error: TypeError: myFunc is not a function
myFunc === 'japp'
```

## So why is this pattern around?

IIFEs are very useful to

- limit the scope
  if you declare

  ```
  var test = 'test'; // var test actually will be assigned as a property of the current context (this)
  window.test = 'test'; // so you pollute the global namespace which is not a good practice
  ```

  so this would be mouch better

  ```
  (function() {
      var test = 'test';
  })();
  ```
- another very good thigs with IIFs is that you can achieve a design with "privates"

  ```
  var myFunc;
  (function() {
      var i = 0; // i is available for myFunc with private access
      myFunc = function() { console.log( ++i ) };
  })();
  myFunc(); // logs 1
  myFunc(); // logs 2
  ```