# Why do JQuery uses IIFE (Immediately invoked function expression)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iife

I got an explanation that so it won't pollute the global variable environment.
But why not just declare normal function and call it at the end?

```
function$(){ some awesome code here with variables declared with var keyword}
$();
```

Comment: _"why not just declare normal function"_ Because declaring a normal function that only does one thing (setup jQuery) would in itself be polluting the global scope

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339735/javascript-self-executing-functions-why-to-use-them-if-i-can-create-local-sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a function like:

```
function doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

It is created under `window`, and it is accessible as `window.doSomething`. So even if the variables inside the function do not *spill* outside, the function name itself pollutes the global namespace. Thus it may potentially conflict with the custom functions developer may wish to use.

Instead, when you use IIFE, and expose the functions under `jQuery` or `$`, the global namespace remains clear.

Comment: Ok. I still don't fully get it. can you further elaborate on how it may conflict with what kind of custom functions? what do you mean by custom functions?  jQuery or $ exposed anyway so it will conflict with variables declared by same name in global namespace anyway

Comment: Say jQuery uses a function `doSomething` but unaware of that you also need to create a new function `doSomething`. It would overwrite the jQuery's `doSomething` function. As a result it would cause an unwanted bug in your program. With that function inside jQuery namespace, your `doSomething` will not override it.